# Is there a mailing list for upcoming Microsoft Windows Updates?

Tags: windows

Is there a newsletter/mailing list of upcoming Windows Updates? I ask because there was a recent IE10 forced upgrade for Windows 7 users that affected the stability of an application we have. To avoid this potential problem in the future, I'd like to keep tabs on upcoming windows Update releases in the future.

I found this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/security/dd252948.aspx

But that seems specific to patches. Anything for general updates/releases (such as the IE10 upgrade)?

For clarification, this is not an internal tool, so blocking and/or managing updates is not an option.

Thanks!

Update: Moved from security

Comment: WSUS - but yeah your link is correct.  http://superuser.com/questions/391215/how-to-receive-email-rss-notifications-about-windows-update

Comment: For IE upgrades your best bet is probably the [IE Team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/). There were multiple posts in the run up to IE10's release to Win7 etc. (and on the steps to block automatic updating).

Comment: +1 It'd be great to know what's coming up to be pushed out. Some of my system's don't work with IE10 either, and not everyone is on a domain managed computer, so WSUS can't help with all of it.  I just need to be prepared for the barrage of support calls!

Answer (score 6):

If you are having these issues you should look into potentially setting up a WSUS server so that you can control what updates get pushed to your clients.  That way you can test all updates before releasing to your clients.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this isn't an internal tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread - but to add some clarification.  The Advanced Security Bulletin Releases also includes:

- Updated versions of the Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal
  Tool
- Non-security, high-priority updates on Microsoft Update, Windows Update, and Windows Server Update Services

Basically if it's being released on Patch Tuesday it's included in the advanced notification.